# How can I make an background-Image show in my div?

Tags: html, css

So, I want to make my first child in my `div.missions`,

however it doesn't show? It only shows the 2nd childs background-color, can someone help me?

Here is my Code

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="mission">
   <div> <h2> Our Goal </h2> </div>
   <div> <p> We want everyone around the globe to have an understanding of mathmatics. Mathmatics is a pretty hard subject to many and we want everyone to be able to solve problems, weather they are easy or hard. At Summit we want to spread knowledge to everyone. </p> </div>
 </div>
```

Here is some of my CSS:

```
.mission{
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
}

.mission div:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url("MountainImage3.jpg");
    background-size: contain; 
}

.mission div:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #48cae4;
    padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be the filepath to your image - your code works when using a working image filepath:

```css
.mission {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
}

.mission div:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1200/1600");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;/* added to center image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;/* added to avoid repetition of image */
}

.mission div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #48cae4;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mission">
  <div>
    <h2> Our Goal </h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> We want everyone around the globe to have an understanding of mathmatics. Mathmatics is a pretty hard subject to many and we want everyone to be able to solve problems, weather they are easy or hard. At Summit we want to spread knowledge to everyone.
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait, why can't I use "images/SummitHome1.jpg"? I have recently gotten a domain "www.summ.ga", has that changed anything? Do you think you can check my repl : https://replit.com/@TahaParacha1/Summit#index.html ?

btw I use cloudfare, if that changes anything..?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it that also in CSS arrays starts at 0? It that case it would be:

```
.mission div:nth-child(0) {
    background-image: url("MountainImage3.jpg");
    background-size: contain; 
}

.mission div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #48cae4;
    padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: hmm, I tried that. I didn't work?

Comment: No, the first child *is*  nth-child(1)